# QGIS 3.2 What is the Windows path for Python Resources

Tags: qgis, python

I'm trying to follow the instructions in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rUShqJde2CA. At time stamp 1:53 he's talking about adding a custom Python script he provides (I have no experience whatsoever with Python and only a little with QGIS) where QGIS will be able to find it. But I think he's using a Mac so his directions don't translate. Where do I find the Windows directory where he wants me to put this script? (I deleted my Google account so I can't leave a YouTube comment.)

Comment: When trying to follow this sort of tutorial, don't forget that QGIS 2.6 was released a long time ago and QGIS 3.x is very different to QGIS 2.x. Particularly with scripts.

Answer (score 0):

It depends where, and how you installed QGIS and what version you are using.

For example it for QGIS 2.6 on a regular installer it would be:

"C:\Program Files\QGIS Brighton\bin"

But just use the *bin* folder in the QGIS install directory.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I could determine that all the steps he showed in that tutorial weren't necessary because of his older version, but I knew there had to be a place for scripts. I was able to get it working, so thank you very much :)